# Python Unittest module not compatible with typing?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Tying to set up a simple test suite, I have src/main.py and src/tests.py. I am getting this error.

```
  File "main.py", line 26
    def error(msg: str) -> int:
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code is

```
from main import error
from typing import *
import unittest


class TestMainFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_error():
        result = error("e")
        self.assertEqual(result, 0)

unittest.main()
```

Is there any way to fix this? The error() function works fine when running main.py. Is the unittest module just not compatible with typing? If so, how do I get around this?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the unit test module, the code in your unit test isn't typed. Most likely you're not using a version of python that uses typing